# Expected identifier or '(' before '.' token

Tags: objective-c, xcode, struct

I'm new to Objective-C so I'm using a book to get to grips with it. I'm at a bit where it's explaining structs and I can't for the life of me get them to work.

I have the following code:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{

    struct node
    {
        int nodeID;
        int x;
        int y;
        BOOL isActive;
    };

    typedef struct node myNode;

    myNode.nodeID = 1;

}
```

and I'm getting the error written in the title. Every time I search for this error online I found different variations such as 'before '>' token' or 'before '}' token' but i can't find anything with the '.' token and it's really frustrating and I assume it's somethings ridiculously trivial and basic. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I understand you, Objective-c can be a pain in the butt when trying to learn it, but it is really a good object-orented-programming language once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got it sorted now, I used the following and it seems to be fixed now:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{    

    struct node
    {
        int nodeID;
        int x;
        int y;
        BOOL isActive;
    };

    struct node myNode;

    myNode.nodeID = 1;
    myNode.x = 100;
    myNode.y = 200;
    myNode.isActive = TRUE;

}
```

Thanks for all your help Darth! :)

Comment: Glad you could figure it out (mostly) by yourself! Always handy in the learning process.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're trying to modify the actual type itself. `nodeA` is now the type of that struct, much like `int`. You need to do something like `nodeA myNode`, then you would be able to perform `myNode.nodeID = 1` without error.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. However doing that produces a similar error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'myNode'

Comment: It has just occurred to me that I have failed to mention I am doing this with the iPhone SDK, it didn't occur to me that this might make a difference. Does it?

Comment: Could you perhaps post the code surrounding the offending line, or perhaps the function containing it?

Comment: That comment just fixed it for me, I wasn't declaring all of this within a function, it was just sat in my .m file after @implementation. I feel slightly dim now haha. Thanks for all your help! :)

Comment: Okay that still didn't fix it, I've edited the original post to include the function.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem with the original code was, it was trying to make myNode a type name using typedef. Thus, myNode is NOT a variable that assignment can happen to. Rather, it was another alias for struct node.